# Nesting a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, sequel

I have a method that selects all the rows from my table like this:

```
smtp_status_raw = my_table.select(:message, :is_valid, :hostname).map { |h| h.values }
```

This returns an array that's like this:

```
[{:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"1"}, {:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"2"}, {:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"3}]
```

Using the above information, I want to create a hash that looks like this:

```
{ 
:node_status => 
    {
        {:hostname => "1", :message: "blah"},
        {:hostname => "2", :message: "blah"},
        {:hostname => "3", :message: "blah"}
    }
}
```

First of all, my question - is it possible to create a hash like the above? In the above example Sequel query, I have three objects which are three separate hosts, and I want to add those three hosts into a `:node_status` key. Is that possible? If that's not a valid hash, what is an alternative?

Second, this is what I've tried:

```
# Initialize the hash
smtp_status_hash = { :node_status: => nil }
```

I've initialized the `smtp_status_hash` hash with a `node_status` key in it, but I am not sure how to nest the query results..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a valid hash, because you have 3 values, but no keys in the `:node_status` subhash. You could do something like:

```
smtp_status_raw = [
  {:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"1"},
  {:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"2"},
  {:message=>"blah", :is_valid=>true, :hostname=>"3"}
]

{
  node_status: smtp_status_raw.collect do |hash|
    hash.reject { |key, value| key == :is_valid }
  end
}
```

to get the values in `:node_status` as an array:

```
{
  :node_status=>[
    {:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"1"},
    {:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"2"},
    {:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"3"}
  ]
}
```

Or you could do something like:

```
{
  node_status: smtp_status_raw.collect do |hash|
    [hash[:hostname], hash[:message]]
  end.to_h
}
```

which sets up a sub hash with the `key` being the `:hostname` and `value` being `:message`:

```
{
  :node_status=>{
    "1"=>"blah",
    "2"=>"blah",
    "3"=>"blah"
  }
}
```

or if you had more keys you wanted to keep:

```
{
  node_status: smtp_status_raw.collect do |hash|
    [hash[:hostname], hash.reject { |key, value| key == :is_valid }]
  end.to_h
}
```

which is still a hash where the `key` is the `:hostname` but the `value` has another hash:

```
{
  :node_status=>{
    "1"=>{:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"1"},
    "2"=>{:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"2"},
    "3"=>{:message=>"blah", :hostname=>"3"}
  }
}
```

To set the values of a key after the `Hash` has been created you can do something like:

```
smtp_status_hash = { node_status:  nil }
smtp_status_hash[:node_status] = "Whatever you want here"
```

You can read more about [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Hash.html) and its methods, and how you can `select` and `reject` to keep or remove keys from a hash. Hashes, though are a dictionary structure and must always have a `key` and a single `value`, though that value may be an `Array` or another `Hash`.

Comment: Hey Simple. Can you explain the difference between my "desired" hash in my question, vs the first hash in your example? It seems you turned it into an array, right?

Comment: Yeah it's just an array nested in `:node_status` instead of a hash. So the only reason your desired hash wasn't a valid hash was because you had `:node_status => {...}` instead of `:node_status => [...]` which would be telling Ruby that you wanted a key/value pair for each of the nodes, instead of just a list of them, and only giving values (or, only giving keys with no values)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`smtp_status_hash = {:node_status=>[]}; my_table.select(:message, :is_valid, :hostname).map{ |h| h.values }.each{|i| smtp_status_hash[:node_status]  << (i)}`